# Trying to find a book - main character was clone (Milo)

Tags: story-identification, clones

I spent few hours on google and google did bring me to this site at last :)

I'm looking for book - in fact series of books and i  remember (think is correct):

1) At beginning main character - i remember his name as Milo (but this was Croatian translation, so...) was awaken in some kind of laboratory (there is some kind A.I. that controls him) or something and he investigates surroundings in some kind of flying vessel(advanced). It is located somewhere in Antarctica or similar but surrounded with ice. And he escapes once :)

2) all places that are inhabited are villages/towns surrounded by huge walls and all other are some vast land and jungle. I think there was some talking cat (panther or some other big cat). There is some kinds of flying zeppelins that fly between this habited places.

3) main character is in some sort clone but i cant explain, cause don't remember it well.

If someone knows about this book i say THANKS in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps "Nebeski gospodari"?

http://www.superknjizara.hr/?page=knjiga&id_knjiga=3846

Original name "The Sky Lords" by John Brosnan.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sky_Lords